# Header not redirecting upon successful login

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to finish a login system. It works properly other than not redirecting through the header function. I have done debugging to show that it gets to the header function when logging in but the header function does not execute.

Here is the code for the login page. I have it set to load the page then upon submitting the form it reloads itself and executes the php code.

```
<?php
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if(empty($username)) {
            $usernamerr = 'Username missing';
            $errflag=true;
        }
        if(empty($password)) {
            $passerr = 'Password missing';
            $errflag=true;

        }
    }

    $qry="SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE Username='$username' AND Pword = '$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful

            $query="SELECT * FROM GROUPING WHERE Username='$username'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            $group = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


            if($group['Admin_flag'] === '1')
            {
                header("location:homeAdmin.php");
                exit();
            }
            else{
                header("location:home.php");
                exit();
            }
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !$errflag){
            $queryerr = 'user name and password not found';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1 align=center class="green">Welcome to the Schneider Electric Login Page.</h1>


<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <ul class="err">
        <li><?php echo $usernamerr;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $passerr;?></li>
        <li><?php echo $queryerr;?></li>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116"><div align="right" class="arial">Username</div></td>
    <td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right" class="arial">Password</div></td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is connection.php that gets included at the beginning

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "database";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for HTTP header manipulation to work properly your script must not have sent any other output to the client yet.

The typical way to handle this is to use output buffering.

Have a look at [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/ob_start) and [ob_end_flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)

So, you would want to call `ob_start` at the beginning of your script, before doing anything else. Then, the last part of your script should call `ob_end_flush()` to actually send the output to the client.

```
<?php
     ob_start();

      //Include database connection details
     require_once('connection.php');

     //Array to store validation errors
     $errmsg_arr = array();

     // ...  the rest of your script follows ...

     // ...  at some point you call the header function to redirect
 ?>
 <html>

 <head>
     <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
      <h1 align=center class="green">Welcome to the Schneider Electric Login Page.</h1>
       <form name="loginform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">

         <!--   The rest of your HTML form goes here -->

      </form>
  </body>

  </html>

<?php
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: That didn't manage to get it unfortunately. It still just reloads the same page. I put a die in the if statement right before the header function and it works so it does reach that point.

Comment: @todaroa, and when you put the `die` statement in, do you see any output from that page on the screen? If you do then that's your problem. If not, then the problem is somewhere else..

Comment: I do see the output of the die statement. I used it purely for debugging and removed it and still had the error.

Comment: @todaroa, sometimes your might have empty spaces.. that would do it.

Comment: I checked for blank spaces before the PHP code and there were none.

Comment: and the script is not included in another page/script, right? I'm really at a loss. This sort of problem is almost always solved with `ob_start()`

Comment: I did have it originally redirecting to another php file with purely the script in it then redirecting. I'm not sure if that is the problem .

Comment: I managed to get it. There was an authoring issue when I was attempting to verify that it was the person in the homeAdmin.php file.

Comment: so basically you redirected to a page that redirected right back to the orginal login page... Been there done that... learned to be careful with multiple redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You might try making the `L` in location capitalized: Location. If that doesn't work, try adding the full path to the homeAdmin.php and home.php files:

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/homeAdmin.php');

header('Location: http://www.domain.com/home.php');
```

Comment: That didn't get it. I tried changing the l to uppercase and the full path but neither seem to execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is Working fine for me.. Add **ob_start();**  and     remove spaces after  and Change Header as **L** and give one space after Location

```
<?php
ob_start();
//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(empty($username)) {
        $usernamerr = 'Username missing';
        $errflag=true;
    }
    if(empty($password)) {
        $passerr = 'Password missing';
        $errflag=true;

    }
}

$qry="SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE Username='$username' AND Pword = '$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful

        $query="SELECT * FROM GROUPING WHERE Username='$username'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $group = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


        if($group['Admin_flag'] === '1')
        {
            header("Location: homeAdmin.php");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            header("Location: home.php");
            exit();
        }
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !$errflag){
        $queryerr = 'user name and password not found';
        }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: I did a copy and paste into the file and it was not successful.

Comment: Please check the condition works or not..follow this...  if($group['Admin_flag'] === '1')
            { echo"Success"; exit;
                header("location:homeAdmin.php");
                exit();
            }